# C# making aero glass form a MDI one causes weird background color

Tags: c#, background-color, mdi, aero, aero-glass

I have a fullscreen form with aero glass enabled which is working fine until I set "IsMdiContainer" to "true". The form still has the aero effect but everything behind it is shown with an insane brightness.

Here's a picture for clarification, lower picture with "IsMdiContainer" disabled, upper one enabled: http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/4981/aeroproblem.jpg

Why's that happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: when you set this property form displays sunken client area with a raised border.

Comment: I can't explain why, but now after a windows reboot, everyhting is working as expected without any changes to the code.
Very strange...